# 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! when I add my custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm making a filter because I have an array with objects that have a different set of keys, but they are just the same in terms of their values. 

This is my custom filter

```
.filter("transactionFilter", function ($filter) {
return function (data) {

    if (angular.isArray(data)) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function(value , key){
          if(value.type === 'Delivery'){
            result.push({
              "customer_name" : value.customer_id.owner_name,
              "date" : value.delivery_date,
              "total_amount" : value.total_amount,
              "type" : value.type,
              "user" : value.user     
            });
          }else {
            result.push({
              "customer_name" : value.customer_name,
              "date" : value.date,
              "total_amount" : value.total_amount,
              "type" : value.type,
              "user" : value.user    
            });
          }
        });
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
});
```

I applying my filter in my view like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactions | transactionFilter">
  {{transaction}}
</tr>
```

But when I apply my filter I got an error which is 
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: Can you recreate this in a simple Plunker? Nothing jumps out as immediately obvious here. Usually you get this error because there is a side effect that causes a change on a watched item... which in turn causes the `$digest` loop to run again. Do you have a `$watch` somewhere that we can't see?

Comment: You always create new objects during filtering - so result is always new. Thats the reason why it fails. Creating new objects in filters is bad idea. (Unless this is strings/numbers)

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I already change my implementation. What I did is I put my filter in my controller like this $scope.transactions = $filter('transactionFilter')(data);

Answer (score -1):

You create new objects in your collection while you are iterating over the collection... never a good idee.

Filters should be used to filter, not to transform your model.

Try this:

```
$scope.myTransactions = function () {

    var result = [];
    _.each($scope.transactions, function (transaction) {
        if (angular.isArray(transaction)) {
            angular.forEach(transaction, function (value, key) {
                if (value.type === 'Delivery') {
                    result.push({
                        "customer_name": value.customer_id.owner_name,
                        "date": value.delivery_date,
                        "total_amount": value.total_amount,
                        "type": value.type,
                        "user": value.user
                    });
                } else {
                    result.push({
                        "customer_name": value.customer_name,
                        "date": value.date,
                        "total_amount": value.total_amount,
                        "type": value.type,
                        "user": value.user
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            result.push(transaction);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Or re-use your code:

```
$scope.myTransactions= $filter('transactionFilter')($scope.transactions);
```

And use this new model in your view.

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in myTransactions">
  {{transaction}}
</tr>
```